# List Terms in Category

Tags: categories, taxonomy, terms

I want to list all terms of a specific taxonomy used in a category.

Like I have a taxonomy called 'Manufacturer' and a category 'Shoes'. Each post in this category has a term like 'Nike', 'Adidas' or 'Reebok' and of course there are some posts having the same term.

And on the archive page I want to list all the terms used in this category and not terms like 'American Apparel', used in in the category "Shirts".

I hope you understand my problem and have a good idea for solving this problem.

Thanks in advance,
Timo

Answer (score 2):

Since you are in a category the your query will get the posts of that category, you only need to add 'posts_per_page' => -1 to that query so it will get you all the posts in that category and not the default "at most" number.

so something like:

```
 query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=-1' );
```

this will will give you all of the posts of that category as we said before, next you loop through the posts and collect the terms in to an array

```
$Manufacturer = array();
while (have_posts()){
    // loop over the posts and collect thier term ID's into $Manufacturer array
    the_posts();
    $terms =wp_get_object_terms($post->ID,'Manufacturer');
    if (count($terms)) {
        foreach ($terms as $term){
            if (!in_array($term->term_id,$Manufacturer)){
                $Manufacturer[] = $term->term_id;
            }
        }
    }
}
//here you have an array $Manufacturer with the id's of only terms with posts in the current category
//so you can do what ever you want with them.
//rewind the posts so you could display them normally without creating a new WP_query object
rewind_posts();
```

Answer (score 1):

This article might be helpful: http://www.leewillis.co.uk/wordpress-taxonomies-to-create-a-product-directory/

Comment: Not for me in this case. But thanks anyway!